# Import png into Excel and change its height and width

Tags: python, excel, image, xlsxwriter

I use the following code to import the `image.png` file into the excel sheet `image_in_excel.xlsx` at cell location `D5`. I also attempt to change the width and height of the imported image.

**Issue**:
The image imports successfully. However, irrespective of whatever I set the 'width' and 'height' in python code, the imported image always measures to be Height=11.25" and Width= 22.01" in Excel (**see attached photo**). Also the aspect ratio seems to be locked.

**Question**:
How to import png to xlsx file at a particular location and then change the imported photo's dimension?

```
import xlsxwriter

# Create a new Excel file
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('image_in_excel.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Insert the PNG image
image_file = 'image.png'
worksheet.insert_image('D5', image_file, {'width': 1, 'height': 20})

# Save the Excel file
workbook.close()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Per the xlsxwriter documentation; https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html?highlight=insert_image#worksheet-insert-image the option to change width and height are 'x_scale' and 'y_scale'.

```
worksheet.insert_image('D5', image_file, {'x_scale': 0.5, 'y_scale': 0.5})
```